# Similar to Menu Bar

Tags: c#, wpf

"A menu bar is something that is assumed to stretch across the control it is contained in by design. That's why it doesn't need a width."

Is there another control like a menu bar that doesn't need a height?

I am trying to create a menu bar which is on the side of my WPF application so I want an unlimited height like when a menu bar can have an unlimited width.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a grid, with the first column being my "menu bar". I add another grid to the 1st column and use rows to set buttons inside, this ensures all buttons are equally divided.

Answer (score 0):

use a groupbox, anchor it to left and dock it to left, adjust its width, now place buttons or controls inside groupbox, you would be able to create an auto height side menubar